# General error: 1005 Can't create table `learning`.`users`

Tags: laravel-6.2

When migrating my DB this error appears, below is my code followed by the error that I am getting when trying to run the migration

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->string('first_name')->nullable();
        $table->string('last_name')->nullable();
        $table->string('city')->nullable();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('role_id');
        $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles')->onDelete('cascade');

    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('users');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Error 1005 is related to foreign key.
make sure you have **roles** table already or it will run before creating **user** table on 
**php artisan  migrate** just place roles migration files before users by editing name of the file.

```
2019_12_07_000000_create_roles_table.php
2019_12_08_000000_create_users_table.php
```